# Python, Getting "SIZE" when trying to log variable

Tags: python

have the following code:

```
import os
import sys
import time

while True:
    #type, timeLogged,timeQueued,orig,rcpt,orcpt,dsnAction,dsnStatus,dsnDiag,dsnMta,bounceCat,srcType,srcMta,dlvType,dlvSourceIp,dlvDestinationIp,dlvEsmtpAvailable,dlvSize,vmta,jobId,envId,queue,vmtaPool
    #Example-: d,5/13/2014 13:57,5/13/2014 13:57,Sandals@origindomain.com,user@gmail.com,,relayed,2.0.0 (success),smtp;250 2.0.0 OK 1400003914 yu4si17175723obb.54 - gsmtp,gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (173.194.64.26),,smtp,[192.168.100.1] (208.115.206.226),smtp,208.115.206.228,173.194.64.26,ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES,CHUNKING,8BITMIME,SIZE,STARTTLS,8405,mx3.yeahdeal.com,28,,gmail.com/mx3.orgindomain.com,orgindomain.com

    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    logList = line.split(',')
    bounceType = str(logList[0])
    if bounceType != "type":
        bounceType = str(logList[0])
        bounceCategory = logList[10]
        emailAddress = logList[4]
        jobId = logList[19]
        fwrite = open("debug.log","a")
        fwrite.write(str(jobId))




fwrite = open("debug2.log","w")
fwrite.write("out of true loop")

dbcon.close()
```

When I check debug.log, jobId is "SIZE" (it should be a number--have also tried without STR, and tried with int()).  Some of the other variables in my logList[] actually are the value that I want them to be.  Very new to python, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please post enough information to make your problem reproducible -- a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help. Show what is being sent to `stdin`, and remove the MySQLdb code since it is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: the comment--is what stdin receives.  'jobId' would be a int value, 1-whatever.  In the above example, jobId is '28'.  will update comment to show values.

Comment: From that example line the 20th field is the value SIZE - print out all the elements in log list I suspect they are not splitting how you expect. Then show what you expect from that example line especially on the first field that differ

Comment: doh.  It is literally "SIZE", I figured I was getting something related to "SIZE" of the variable.  I didn't even notice that!